# login errors Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I get an error that says data mismatch in the expression in my code snippet:

```
    [...]
    If Validate_User() Then
        strUser = Trim(Me.txtIDNumber.Text).ToLower
        Dim frm As New main
        Me.Hide()
        frm.ShowDialog()
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect IDNumber/Password")
    End If
    me1 = txtIDNumber.Text.ToString
    'txtIDNumber.Text = ""
    txtPassword.Text = ""
End Sub

Function Validate_User()
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim bValid As Boolean = False

    Try

        con = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        ' cmd.CommandText = "select ID from students_records where IDNumber = '" & Me.txtIDNumber.Text & "' and MiddleName = '" & Me.txtPassword.Text & "'"
        cmd.CommandText = "select IDNumber from students_records where IDNumber = '" & Me.txtIDNumber.Text & "' and MiddleName = '" & Me.txtPassword.Text & "'"

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            bValid = True
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    Return bValid
End Function
```

Comment: When you step through the code, what do you see after the line `cmd.CommandText =` as the value of the CommandText?

Comment: Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'CIT_Teachers_Evaluation_System.studentslogin.txtIDNumber.get'

Comment: Where does it fail? What happens immediately before it fails? Try making a minimal command-line application... like this one http://paste.ubuntu.com/6241131/ and see where you fail. Good luck!